# $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}(t)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, field-theory, extension-field, rational-functions

Let $F = \mathbb{R}(t)$ be a field of rational functions in an indeterminate $t$. Set $ε = \frac{1}{t}$.

I have to show that $0 < ε < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ and that $\frac{1}{n}$ does not tend to the limit $0$ in $F$.

Could the reason for $ε < \frac{1}{n}$ for any $n$ be, that $t$ is an upper bound for $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}(t)$ and thus no matter what $n$ we choose, $ε < \frac{1}{n}$ for all sufficiently large $t$?

And that $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge to 0, is it because taking the formal definition of a limit, we can always find sufficiently large $t$ such that $|\frac{1}{n} – L| > ε$?

All in all I would like to ask for a hint at how to approach the question.

Comment: How can $t$ be "sufficiently large" if it is the indeterminate?

Comment: Note that the symbol $<$ has a different meaning in $\Bbb R(t)$ than it does in $\Bbb R$. What is the meaning of $0<\epsilon$ in $\Bbb R(t)$? What is the meaning of $\epsilon<r$ in $\Bbb R(t)$ when $r$ is a real number (for instance $r=\frac1n$)?

Comment: This ordered field is "non-archimedean".  To be complete, your statement should specify the ordering to be used.  You are correct that $1/n$ does not converge to $0$ in the order topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\varepsilon<\frac1n&\iff\frac1t<\frac1n\\&\iff n<t\\&\iff t-n>0,\end{align}which is true, by the definition of the order relation in $\Bbb R(t)$.

And you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$ precisely because there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\frac1n>\varepsilon$.